# LDAP SSH + PubKey auth Fallback

Tags: linux, centos, openldap, pam, pam-ldap

I have followed this guide here : https://github.com/jirutka/ssh-ldap-pubkey
In order to setup a LDAP server that allows authentication requesting both Password and Public Key in order to login.

Now while all this seems like a very good idea, ssh server runs this scripts (as described in the guide) everytime someone logs in

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/ssh-ldap-pubkey-wrapper
```

This will call to my LDAP server and attempt to retreive the public key for the current user.
I would like to know how I could have a fallback system in the event the LDAP server is not reachable for any reasons. 
I have already considered a second LDAP server for redundancy, but would like to know how how to approach this locally

ps : Using CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the environments I'm working there are at least two LDAP servers operated, to prevent the problem(s) you're currently thinking about. So, if possible, set up a second LDAP server, preferably on a different physical host than the first one.

Additionally, you could check if it's worth to implement the [name service cache daemon (nscd)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd), which is

> a daemon that provides a cache for the most common name service requests.

(Not sure if this works for SSH keys, but you'll find out.) In section `2.2.2.3. NSCD configuration` of [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html) tutorial you'll find a small how-to.

Also, you could have a look at the [system security services daemon sssd](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/), which is

> a system daemon. Its primary function is to provide access to identity and authentication remote resource through a common framework that can provide caching and offline support to the system.

(In my opinion, this is the more modern way to go instead of `nscd`.)
 Check out [this](https://wiki.contribs.org/Client_Authentication:Centos_via_sssd/ldap) for some general notes about configuration on `CentOS`, and [that](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/openssh-sssd.html) for information specifically about SSH keys.